# Text view is not updating new value after onResume in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i am using a timer in xamarin forms. I have two buttons[start and stop] and a text view to update timer it is working fine. I want to show timer even if an app is closed for this I am saving app closing time in onSleep and in onResume, I am getting saved time and comparing with a current time. after again i am starting timer but text view is not updating with a timer.

Below is my Code:

```
public void RunTimer()
{       
    TimeSpan TimeElement = new TimeSpan();
    Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), () => {
        TotalTime = TotalTime + TimeElement.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
        timerTextView.Text = string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", TotalTime);
        Settings.WorkTime = TotalTime.ToString();
        // Save time before app close
        Settings.beforeAppCloseTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        _isRunning = Settings._isRunning;
        return _isRunning;
    });
}
```

Comment: `A timer should run even if the app is closed or in sleep`:  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/foreground-services/

Comment: Edited please check once

Comment: How did you update your timer when your Activity in `OnResume` ?